# Haskell: Implementation of a Complete Binary-Leaf Tree

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to generate a complete binary-leaf tree using Haskell.
However, I'm not sure whether I am along the right lines.
I have the following code at the moment (not sure if it's right):

```
data Tree a  = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show,Eq)

listToTree :: [a] -> Tree a

listToTree [] = error "The list cannot be empty"

listToTree [x] = Leaf x
```

I need the function to take in an input list of any basic types and construct a tree using level first order from the list provided as input. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You've made a good start. However all the list elements are going to become leaves, so write a function including "where leaves = map Leaf xs". Now you have a list of trees. If this is empty then error, if it contains one element then that is your complete tree, and if it contains two or more elements then recursively join them pairwise using Branch.

Comment: Thanks, could i just ask what does it mean when it says 'level first order'? Also which function would be best to use? filter or split? I've seen examples but not sure which to go with.

Comment: "Level first order"? You are the one asking the question. I take it this is homework. I guess it means the order of the elements in the tree must be the same as the list. And you don't need "split". Instead think about a list of the form (x1:x2:xs)

Comment: FYI- there is more than one way to do this....  trees can be balanced or unbalanced.  Writing the funciton to create something unblananced would be easy, but the tree would be kind of worthless for many applications.  If you want something balanced, you need to determine your balancing algorithm before going further.